# Implement '*'-operator for classes with fixed code

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have two C++-classes A and B that I can't change for various reasons. However, I'd like to be able to define a multiplication `a*a` and `a*a`. (Think of A as a rotation matrix and b as a vector). I of course could define a `mult(const A& a, const B& b)` but that gets unreadable if I have expressions like `a*a'*b`.

Is there a way to overload the *-operator for these classes without changing their code?

(If this is not possible, was there ever a discussion to add this feature to the language?)

Comment: Make a non-member overload?

Comment: Are you not allowed to edit `A` or `B` at all?

Comment: A and B are autogenerated and I don't want to maintain changes in the generator.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: What is the type of the result of `a * b`?

Comment: @LogicStuff: thanks, that's what I wanted to do, know I know what to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a global `operator*()` function exactly like you would do `mult()`:

```
const B& operator*(const A& a, const B& b) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change the classes at all you can still write a global `operator*` like

```
B operator*(const A& a, const B& b)
```

But you will not be able to modify any of the private members of the classes unless the classes provide accessers to them